# Parallel-series connection of an odd number of solar cells

Tags: solar-cell, parallel, series, solar-energy, mppt

I plan on having the following array in my system:

[image: Screenshot of solar array]

**Vmpp** voltage at max. power point for each cell is **1.67 V**

**Impp** current at max. power point is **18.4 mA**

As the number of cells in the right "Parallel String" is greater than the one on the left, is it ok to assume that the final array Impp current will be somewhere around 92 mA (18.4 mA * 5) and the Vmapp voltage will be 3.34 V (1.67 V * 2,) or do I need to use the parallel string with less cells for this calculation?

I need at least two cells in series to have the voltage for the [SPV1040 MPPT IC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/spv1040.pdf) and would like to use all available space on the board, this is why I have a maximum of 9 cells.

EDIT: Here is [the link for the solar cell's datasheet](https://waf-e.dubudisk.com/anysolar.dubuplus.com/techsupport@anysolar.biz/O18Ae07/DubuDisk/www/Gen3/KXOB25-05X3F%20DATA%20SHEET%20202007.pdf)

Comment: This is ineffcient. Suppose each cell wants to output 1 A. Then the circuit of  SC1,3,5,7 will output 4 A. The circuit of SC2,4,6,8,9 will try to output 5 A but **they cannot**, they will be forced to 4 A by the other circuit. It will be more efficient to make sets of 3 in parallel and connect those 3 sets in series. Then all cells can output their full 1 A. My 1 A is just an example, feel free to replace by 18.4 mA.

Comment: MPPT is easier to do on a single string than on a few parallel ones, since you can regulate the voltage of a specific string. Follow the advice of @Bimpelrekkie .

Comment: The smallest solar panel I heave ever seen is 2V on my solar garden lights. It has four 0.5V solar cells in series on one panel. Maybe you have nine of these 2V solar panels that you say are cells. Solar panels with ten cells in series making 5V are available. Wouldn't that be smaller than many of your separately packaged cells?

Comment: 3 strings of 3 cells ( or even 9 cells in series) and a buck converter, would be better. (Also, what kind of cell emits 1.67V? I suspect it's already 3 or 4 cells in series, but you should have linked its datasheet.)

Comment: I'm afraid I cannot folllow @Bimpelrekkie 's  suggestion as that would give me a Vmpp using the values on the linked datasheet of 5.01 V, which is greater than the maximum 4.2 V wanted output at my SPV1040 MPPT IC. In this case is it less worse to use 9 this way or remove one and not have the limitation?

Comment: What prevents you from putting them all in parallel and boost from there or all in series and buck from there? Assuming a suitable IC choice. Optimizing the panel instead of picking and IC and let the panel suffer.

Comment: @winny Unless I'm missing something, it seems like the SPV1040 *is* a suitable choice for boosting all 9 modules in parallel!

Comment: Yes @Theodore the module can definitely boost that, I think I had in mind the requirement from a previous IC I was using and carried the requirement to this one, a new throughtout reading of the datasheet after your suggestion confirmed that, thank you, and sorry if I wasted someone's time over this simple mistake!

Comment: @joaopedrovbs Although it seems the series-parallel combination won't be necessary for your project, it's a good question in general to leave for posterity.  Hopefully someone (maybe even you) writes an answer based on all the comments.

Comment: Save yourself 11% on the panels and use 8!

Comment: A solar cell is a current source , not a voltage source

Answer (score 1):

I believe it would be (18.4 mA*4) i.e the total current from left side and voltage would be 3.34 V. In series connection of mismatched current and voltage ratings modules, the minimum current of the module will come into effect while the voltage of each module adds up. Similarly, in parallel connection, minimum voltage would come into effect while current of each module adds up.

Let me know if I’m wrong.